# How to convert an array of strings to a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

How do I convert this array :

```
let strArr = ["10100", "10111", "11111", "01010"];
```

into a 2-d array.

The 2-d array will be :-

```
 1 0 1 0 0
 1 0 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: How is `1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0` a 2d array?

Comment: It was lost in the formatting. (Hitting "edit" you could see what he meant but there's  pending fix now so...)

Answer (score 3):

You could get the iterables from string and map numbers.

```js
var array = ["10100", "10111", "11111", "01010"],
    matrix = array.map(s => Array.from(s, Number));
    
console.log(matrix);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ... `Array.from` iterates over the characters of one of the strings, and then calls `Number` on each and returns the results as a new array, effectively turning `"10010"` into `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

If the result needs to be an array of array containing one element per character of a string, you can split each string with an empty string in a loop or map.

```
let res = [];
let strArr = ["10100", "10111", "11111", "01010"];
strArr.map((str) => {
    res.push(str.split(''))
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each item and spread its content into an array - then convert to a number.

`let newArr = strArr.map(item => [...item].map(Number));`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inArr = ["10100", "10111", "11111", "01010"];
let outArr = inArr.map( line => line.split("").map(  item =>  +item  ) );

console.log(outArr);
```

```
let inArr = ["10100", "10111", "11111", "01010"];
let outArr = inArr.map( line => line.split("").map(  item =>  +item  ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

this way, you will have 2d array of zero and ones

```
const newArr = strArr.map((a) => a.split("").map(char => char === "0"? 0: 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let strArr = ["10100", "10111", "11111", "01010"];
let numColumns = strArr[0].length;
let numRows = strArr.length;
let string = strArr.join('');
let result = [];

for (let row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
  result.push([]);
  for (let column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
    result[row].push(parseInt(string.charAt(row*5 + column), 10));
  }
}

console.log(result);
```